# How to route multiple parameters in MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, parameter-passing

I have my default MVC routes setup as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What I want to be able to do is have the following routes in my Search controller hit.

```
.../Search/Uk
.../Search/Uk/County/Buckinghamshire
.../Search/Uk/City/London
.../Search/Uk/Town/Ashford
.../Search/Uk/Postcode/AB-Aberdeen
```

I only have one view called "Index". As I understood routing I presumed I should of been able to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string country)

public ActionResult Index(string country, string searchType, string location)
```

But no cigar, anyone understand what I'm doing wrong, do I need to add in some sort of routes configuration? Infact implementing this I cannot even load the search page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute based routing where you can pass parameters in the route itself.

like,

```
//I hope you have already enabled attribute routing and search controller with RoutePrefix as "search"

[Route("{country}")]
public ActionResult Index(string country)
{
  //Your business logic
}

[Route("{country}/{searchType}/{location}")]
public ActionResult Index(string country, string searchType, string location)
{
  //Your business logic
}
```

[Enabling Attribute based routing : MSND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enabling-attribute-routing)

Comment: I don't seem to have a WebApiConfig class, I have BundleConfig, FilterConfig, IdentityConfig, RouteConfig, Startup.Auth

Comment: Check your `RouteConfig` class, where is your `routes.MapRoute()` written?

Comment: needed this also for my setup [Route("{Search}/{country}/{searchType}/{location}")]

Comment: Please check my comment, It is better to use `RoutePrefix` if you want controller name should be in route.